# Stimulsoft, Assembly 'Stimulsoft.Report.Wpf' is not found,

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report, stimulsoft

I have WPF Application and I have used Stimulsoft version 2015 for reports but i have problem, I can't load 'Stimulsoft.Report.Wpf.dll.

```
StiReport stiReport1 = new StiReport();

stiReport1.Load("Report.mrt");

stiReport1.RenderWithWpf();
stiReport1.ShowWithWpf();
```

> Assembly 'Stimulsoft.Report.Wpf' is not found,

Answer (score 1):

For WPF Applications you have to use Ultimate version. I think you are using .Net version.

.Net:
WinForms Viewer,
WinForms Dot-Matrix Viewer,
WinForms Reports Designer,
Web Viewer,
Report Engine

Ultimate: 
WinForms Viewer,
WinForms DotMatrix Viewer,
WinForms Reports Designer,
WPF Viewer,
WPF DotMatrix Viewer,
WPF Reports Designer,
Silverlight Viewer (Client/Server),
Silverlight Reports Designer (Client/Server),
Silverlight Viewer,
Silverlight Reports Designer,
Web Viewer,
Web Viewer.Fx,
Web Reports Designer,
Report Engine,
Report Engine (Silverlight)

Based on https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products